# "integer out of range" error in a for next statement

Tags: vba, for-loop, integer, range

I've gone nuts on this, and I'm sure the error is right in front of me, I just cant see it. appreciate all the help in debugging the statements below.

I have multiple slides in a ppt presentation. in some of the slides, there is a star shape, and a textbox with text "Hold" or "Yearly". I want to change the color of the star only if there is no textbox with "Hold" or "Yearly".

```
Sub Set_Star_Shape_Color_Green_Test()
    Dim PPApp As Object ' As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres As Object ' As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPSlide As Object ' As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim iShpCnt1 As Integer
    Dim iShpCnt2 As Integer
    Dim iShpCnt3 As Integer
    Dim iSlideCnt As Integer
    Dim iBoxTopPos As Integer
    Dim sHold As String
    Dim sStar As String
    Dim sTbox As String
    Dim sTColor As String
    Dim oShp As Shape

    Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides _
        (PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

    iShpCnt0 = PPSlide.Shapes.Count
    For iShpCnt1 = 1 To iShpCnt0    'PPSlide.Shapes.Count
        iBoxTopPos = 260
        ' iSlideCnt = 2 removed
        sHold = ""
        sStar = ""

        iShpCnt1 = 1
        For iShpCnt1 = 1 To PPSlide.Shapes.Count
            If iShpCnt1 <= PPSlide.Shapes.Count Then
                **Set oSh = PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(iSlideCnt).Shapes(iShpCnt1)  ' this is where i am getting the integer out of range error**
                If oSh.Name.Text Like "*Hold*" Or oSh.Name.Text Like "*Yearly*" Then
                    sHold = oSh.Name
                End If
                If oSh.Name Like "*Star*" Then
                    sStar = oSh.Name
                End If
            End If

        Next

        For iShpCnt2 = 1 To iShpCnt0 ' this fixed the error
            Set oSh = PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(iSlideCnt).Shapes(iShpCnt2)
            If oSh.Name Like "*Star*" And sHold = "" Then
                oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 205, 50) ' change the color to green
            End If
        Next

        ' go to next slide
        If PPSlide.SlideIndex + 1 < PPPres.Slides.Count Then
            PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide PPSlide.SlideIndex + 1
            Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides _
                (PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex + 1)
        End If

    Next

    ' Clean up
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
    Set PPApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the iterator to two.

```
For iSlideCnt = 1 To PPPres.Slides.Count
    iBoxTopPos = 260
    iSlideCnt = 2 <--- right here
```

It will go out of bounds if you have just one slide.

Comment: thanks for replying. there are multiple slides in my ppt so it still should work. anyways, i deleted that statement (iSlideCnt = 2 <--- right here), and the integer out of range error still exist. thanks.

Comment: just want to let others know that i've fixed the error by changing "For iShpCnt1 = 1 To PPSlide.Shapes.Count" to "For iShpCnt1 = 1 To iShpCnt0"